# SwiftUI: make layout relative to a central view

Tags: layout, swiftui

Assume I build a view like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
   @State private var a: String
   @State private var b: String
   @State private var c: String

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
        HStack {
          Text(a)

          // this is the central view
          Text(b).font(.headline)
        }

        Text(c)
      }
   }
}
```

I would like the central text view (the one displaying `b`) to be the anchor of the layout. That is, no matter how other text values change, I would like the central text to always stay in the centre of `MyView` (the centre of the text element and the centre of `MyView` should stay identical) and the other text elements should be laid out around the central one.

How to I achieve this? I tried to look at alignment guides, but I just don't seem to understand how to use them properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some time to learn how alignment works in detail, I managed to arrive at a solution that only uses stacks and custom alignments, with minimal alignment guides and without needing to save any intermediate state. It's purely declarative, so I am supposed this is how SwiftUI designers intended it. I still think that there might have been a better design for it, but one can work with it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var a: String = "AAAAA"
    @State var b: String = "BBBB"
    @State var c: String = "CCCCCC"

    var body: some View {
         VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .mid) {
                // create vertical and horizontal 
                // space to align to
                HStack { Spacer() }
                VStack { Spacer() }

                VStack(alignment: .midX) {
                    Text(self.a)

                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text(self.c)


                        Text(self.b)
                            .font(.title)
                            .border(Color.blue)
                            .alignmentGuide(.midX) { d in
                                (d[.leading] + d[.trailing])/2
                            }
                            .alignmentGuide(.midY) { d in
                                (d[.top] + d[.bottom])/2
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .layoutPriority(1.0)
            .overlay(CrossHair().stroke(Color.pink, lineWidth: 2))

            TextField("", text: self.$b).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension HorizontalAlignment {
    enum MidX : AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return (d[.leading] + d[.trailing])/2
        }
    }

    static let midX = HorizontalAlignment(MidX.self)
}

fileprivate extension VerticalAlignment {
    enum MidY : AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return (d[.top] + d[.bottom])/2
        }
    }

    static let midY = VerticalAlignment(MidY.self)
}

fileprivate extension Alignment {
    static let mid = Alignment(horizontal: .midX, vertical: .midY)
```

Comment: @kontiki Thank you for your insightful comments and tips. I think I managed to improve your solution a bit by eliminating the need for `hs` state, but most of the credit definitely goes to you :)